# JPG picture preview is in color, but all image viewers and editors open the full picture in black and while

Tags: windows-10, pictures

I encountered a really bizarre phenomenon today on my Windows 10. I found and saved a black and white picture on DeviantArt, but when I look at the folder containing that picture along with the other pictures, its small preview appears to be in color. Opening it in Windows Photos, in IrfanView, in Paint, or even in Photoshop results in the full picture being black and while. But where does the color on the preview come from then?

Google search seems to indicate that this might have something to do with "embedded color profile", whatever that is. Is there any way to get more info on that picture's metadata to see where the color comes from? Is there any way to open a full picture in color too?

EDIT: even more bizarrely, the color from the preview fails to appear when the picture is saved, cut or copied into some existing folder with non-picture files. The preview has color only if it is saved in the existing folder with other pictures, in the empty folder where pictures used to be, or in the new empty folder. I suspect it has something to do with the folder type.

The picture in question is below, but fair warning that it has a slightly erotic nature (no explicit nudity though): https://www.deviantart.com/robert-james/art/090411-D04-060a-BW-120499557

Comment: It's tough to guess unless we can see it.

Comment: Please post online the image, or at least let us know its URL on DeviantArt.

Comment: What is the colorspace of the image? Might be CMYK being viewed as B&W but somehow stored as CMYK which is mainly a print format.

Comment: @Tetsujin added the link to the image in the question body.

Comment: @harrymc added the link to the image in the question body.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 how do I check the colorspace? Windows file properties don't specify them. Also, posted the link to the image in the question body.

Comment: @UchuuStranger Most photo viewers should show you those details. If nothing you currently have works, try using [ExifTool](https://sourceforge.net/projects/exiftool/) to view a ton of metadata connected to an image. It is a command line tool that has Linux, macOS and Windows variants; all the same usage and output.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 tried it, color space data is RGB. So I guess it's a thumbnail replacement just like Aganju suggested, though I don't see anything in ExifTool metadata that suggests it. I want to find a way to see that thumbnail metadata somehow.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 nevermind, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349622/extract-thumbnail-from-jpeg-file), and it describes how to use exiftool to extract a thumbnail. I confirmed that it's the only thumbnail that the file contains, with a small resolution of 160x107. Still interesting that separate thumbnails are a thing though, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many picture formats have an embedded 'thumbnail', which has been created by the writing program. It could be that your file has a colored thumbnail, but a b/w full picture - whichever tool was used to create it seem to support this behavior.
*If* this is the case, there is nothing you can do, except go back to the source for the full color picture - it simply is not inside your file. Only that small preview thumbnail will be available in color.

Without seeing and analyzing your file, that's my best guess, and it could be wrong of course...

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner, had a busy week. Added the link in the question body above. Does that mean that certain writing programs allow substituting thumbnails entirely? Or is it only the color scheme? I don't particularly care about this particular picture at this point, but the possibility of replacing the thumbnail with a completely different picture intrigues me, as I never encountered that before.

Comment: @UchuuStranger - nothing keeps you or anyone to write a program that writes an unrelated picture into the thumbnail location, so I am sure such code exists (but I don’t know any personally). The detail format specification(and therefore location of the thumbnail) of most picture files are public.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At the suggestion in comments above I used exiftool, and with the command I found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349622/extract-thumbnail-from-jpeg-file) I extracted a thumbnail.